# how to give coordinates to an android emulator to get proximity alert

Tags: android, coordinates, telnet, proximity

I am trying to implement an android simple code that uses proximityalerts and gives an alert when entering and exiting some defined area

the code runs without errors but i would like to test if it works with coordinates (first not in the area, then goes in should receive an alert, then exits and receive another alert) so i googled how to use telnet to give lat,long but all i found is giving fixed values

is there another way to approach this? 
PS: I am using android studio :)

EDIT: i figured out how to change the coordinates and i followed a tutorial to get proximity test ... the code runs without any errors but the intent to give the alert does not seem to fire
here is my code:
*MainActivity*

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    LocationManager lm;
    double lat=32.001271,long1=35.950375;    //Defining Latitude & Longitude
    float radius=100;                         //Defining Radius
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lm=(LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);


        Intent i= new Intent("com.example.hala.proximityalert");           //Custom Action
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), -1, i, 0);
        lm.addProximityAlert(lat, long1, radius, -1, pi);



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

*ProximityReceiver*

```
public class ProximityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
// The reciever gets the Context & the Intent that fired the broadcast as arg0 & agr1
        String k=LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;
// Key for determining whether user is leaving or entering
        boolean state=arg1.getBooleanExtra(k, false);
//Gives whether the user is entering or leaving in boolean form
        if(state){
// Call the Notification Service or anything else that you would like to do here
            Toast.makeText(arg0, "Welcome to my Area", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
//Other custom Notification
            Toast.makeText(arg0, "Thank you for visiting my Area,come back again !!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
}
```

so if anyone has an idea on why it doesn't fire i would really appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

You can give coordinates via :

> Eclipse -> DDMS -> Emulator Control tab -> Give coordinate includes
>   latitude and longitude

Comment: sorry i forgot to say i am using android studio , also i don't want just one coordinate, as i said i want to simulate a user going in and then exiting a certain area